# How to use php simpleHTMLdom to parse HTML an get strings?

Tags: html-parsing, simple-html-dom

how to use simpleHTMLdom to get a string that is inside a `<th>` tag (and there is many other `<th>`) For example :

```
<th>name</th>
    <td>john</td>
<th>age</th>
    <td>32</td>
```

How to get 32 ? note that sometimes, the website i'm parsing, doesn't contain the same number of `<th>` sometimes there is no `<th>name</th>` so i cant do : `$html->find('th',1)` to get age and go to `<td>` to get 32

Any way to perform something like : `$html->find('age')` ?

Thank you

Comment: You have to loop through all 'th' and find index of age and use that index to find its 'td'.

Comment: I agree with you @Malik but <th> (even for <td>) do not have class or id how to find index of age ? i'm looking for a way to find by string for example or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something like this:

```
$ageIndex = 0;
foreach($html->find('th') as $key => $val)
{
  if($val->innertext == 'age')
  {
     $ageIndex = $key;
     break;
  }
}

$age = $html->find('td',$ageIndex);
```